# Angular Mat group form layout add spaces between inputs fields and change the size of inputs fields to be smaller

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

[image]
update: The spaces issue resolved. I also made the size of each input field smaller so user can view all inputs without using scroll bar. But the size of label is too small and hard to read. I want to increase the size of the mat-dialog-content so I can increase the size of each input fields as well. I tried to add "width":100% and 1800px in dialog open's config, but the width not increases. is there anyway to increase the width of dialog?

```
  onAddRestriction() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(RpoRestrictionCriteriaDialogComponent, {
      width: '1800px',
    });
```

I have a dialog that each input field is closely placed next to each others with no space between. I'm trying to add spaces between them. I tried to change the width of mat-form-field to 45%, and justify-contents to space-between/space-around. But there are still no space between input fields.

I also need to make the size of each input field smaller, so user don't need to drag the horizontal scroll bar to view all the input fields.

Is there anyway to set the input fields to be smaller?

my html of the dialog:

```
<div mat-dialog-content class="add-restriction-dialog">
  <div [formGroup]="form">
    <ng-container formArrayName="restrictions">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let restrictionForm of restrictions.controls; let i = index">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <div class="dialog-input-container">
            <mat-form-field class="dialog-input" appearance="standard">
              <mat-label>Rpo Restriction Criteria Id:</mat-label>
              <input matInput placeholder="Rpo Restriction Criteria Id..." formControlName="rpoRestrictionCriteriaId" maxlength="10" max="9999999999"
                     required>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field class="dialog-input" appearance="standard">
              <mat-label>Vin Group Criteria Id:</mat-label>
              <input matInput placeholder="Vin Group Criteria Id..." formControlName="vinGroupCriteriaId" maxlength="10" max="9999999999"
                     required>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field class="dialog-input" appearance="standard">
              <mat-label>Rpo Restriction Sequence Number:</mat-label>
              <input matInput placeholder="Rpo Restriction Sequence Number..." formControlName="rpoRestrictionSequenceNumber" maxlength="10" max="9999999999"
                     required>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
              <mat-label>Operator:</mat-label>
              <mat-select formControlName="operator" placeholder="operator..." required>
                <mat-option value="&">&</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="-">-</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
              <mat-label>Rpo Restriction Value:</mat-label>
              <input matInput formControlName="value" placeholder="Rpo Restriction Value..." required>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field class="dialog-input" appearance="standard">
              <mat-label>Record Created By:</mat-label>
              <input matInput placeholder="Record Created By..." formControlName="recordCreatedBy" maxlength="10" max="9999999999"
                     required>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field class="dialog-input" appearance="standard">
              <mat-label>Delete Indicator:</mat-label>
              <input matInput placeholder="Delete Indicator..." formControlName="deleteIndicator" maxlength="10" max="9999999999"
                     required>
            </mat-form-field>

            <div class="dialog-remove-container">
              <mat-icon class="delete-btn" (click)="removeRestriction(i)">
                delete_forever
              </mat-icon>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>

    <button mat-button (click)="addAdditionalRestriction()" type="button">
      + Add Restriction
    </button>

    <div mat-dialog-actions>
      <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]>Cancel</button>
      <button mat-button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="!form.valid">
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
mat-header-cell, mat-cell {
  justify-content: center;
}

.dialog-input-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.dialog-input{
  width: 45%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dialog-remove-container{
  margin-left: 1%;
}
```

I hope the result to be like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to overcome this problem. You can add padding on left and right of .mat-form-field in CSS.

```css
.mat-form-field{
  padding-left: 1vw;
  padding-right: 1vw;
}
```

[image]